# Camunda memory leak in spring boot starter

Tags: spring-boot, memory-leaks, camunda

we use camunda as our process engine and have like 10K running processes in production. The problem is, that our service goes instantly about once a day out of memory. Here is a screenshot of grafana, which shows the memory consumption.

[image]

We tried to cluster the service and now it runs on 2 instances, but as you see, the memory consumption grows anyway on both.

After analyzing the heapdump we figured out, that it´s the mybatis dependency, which causes the memory leak. Unfortunately it´s included in camunda, so we cannot change it or access it. Did any one had such behavior using camunda? 
Are there any ways to configure how the camunda uses mybatis?

Here is the screenshot of the heapdump:

[image]

Here is our dev. stack:
Open JDK 11,
Postgresql 10.8,
Camunda 7.10.0,
Spring Boot 2.1.12,
camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp 3.2.1

It would be even great, if u know any approach how to handle in such situations.

Cheers,
Andrej

Comment: This sounds as if it justifies a bug report on https://jira.camunda.com/.

Did you try to manually change the dependency version of mybatis?

Also: Did you try this with latest (starter 3.4.x, camunda 7.12)? Is Java 11 a supported platform for starter 3.2 and camunda 7.10?

Comment: Did you try JPA with Camunda?

Comment: Do you have an update? Did you file a JIRA ticket for this or was there another outcome?

Comment: Do you find any solution for this?